# Electric guitar on a mixer

Tags: electric-guitar, mixer, computer

I just got my first electric guitar and am wanting to learn how to play it. now I want to try and let my friends listen in with me via discord. I have a studio microphone that I've connected in an XLR mixer. now I can connect the electric guitar to this and play but to do that I have to disconnect the microphone. so basically what I'm asking is. is there a mixer that allows me to play my guitar and talk through my studio mic at the same time?

thank you in advance

Comment: This is all a bit confused. I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Guitars don't plug into XLR sockets (nor should you try to find adaptors to force them).

Comment: sorry, I should have worded that better it's like a mix between an xlr and a 6,3mm jack. this is the mixer I have: https://www.bax-shop.nl/analoog-mengpaneel/behringer-xenyx-302usb-pa-en-studio-mixer and I could plug it into this (I have edited the question for people to better understand it)

Comment: that doesn't look ready to take a guitar; it's mic & 'consumer line level' suitable for a hifi line out, not guitar. https://www.behringer.com/product.html?modelCode=P0ADV

Comment: I get that it probably isn't supposed to be used for a guitar and that's why I'm asking. is there a mixer where I can hook up a studio mic and a guitar or do I need to get some other stuff (I am not really an audio guy so I don't know anything about gear and stuff)

Comment: That socket is for *either* xlr *or* standard jack. If that works with either guitar or mic, why wouldn't a mixer with two of those sockets work as you require?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me what you really want is an audio interface so you can simultaneously run your guitar and mic into a digital device for recording/sharing. I have one with two input channels that take both guitar cord and XLR mic cable, and a USB output which also serves to power the unit. It only has level controls, no EQ or pan, but is bundled with mixing software that will provide those functions, and more, digitally.

I understand it’s not appropriate to recommend specific products here, but if you search for “audio interface” at your favorite music gear retailer, you should find some options at a range of prices.

Comment: I would recommend an audio interface for practice, but not all audio interfaces will work as standalone mixers.  If OP really needs a mixer then this will not work for him.

Comment: I don't necessarily need a mixer. the mixer is just there for my mic but If I can use an audio interface for both my mic and a guitar then that would be the solution